# Passbook "application/vnd.apple.pkpass" mime type is not recognized

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, passbook, wallet

in my mvc FileContentResult action i return my passbook pass file like this :  `return new FileContentResult(generatedPass, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");` . but downloaded file does not have a extension in pkpass. why is that. i added the mime type to iis server. but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add a filename like this:

```
return File(generatedPass, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass", "my-file-name.pkpass")
```